# How to check if string contains chars which are not in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question. How do I check if a python string contains chars which are not in a given list?

Here is the list (set):

```py
set("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._")
```

Comment: Convert the string to a `set`, then get the difference betweenthe two sets. If this is not empty, the string contains characters not in the set.

Comment: why was this closed with reason "update the question so it focuses on one problem only"? Where is the second problem? The question is definitely clear as is shown by the answers. Please reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to test whether the characters in the string are **not a subset** of the given set of characters. That is straightforward in Python because the `<=` operator tests if one set is a subset of another.

```py
import string

# don't use a mutable set for this purpose
GIVEN = frozenset(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '-._')

def uses_other_chars(s, given=GIVEN):
    return not set(s) <= given
```

Examples:

```py
>>> uses_other_chars('abc')
False
>>> uses_other_chars('Hello!')
True
```

Comment: There's also `set.issuperset`, which takes any iterable.

Comment: Nevermind. I thought it would be faster because it could stop at the first non-member instead of creating a set out of the whole `s` first, but I just checked and it [does that anyway](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1801). Gah.

Answer (score 5):

I always defer to regular expressions when validating strings.

To create a set, you enclose all characters in the set in `[]`.
To check if a string contains any character *not* in a set, add `^` to the beginning.
To check if the string contains one or more members of a set, append `+`.

Given this information, a regular expression to check if a string contains any characters *other than* {a,b,c,d} would look like this:

`[^abcd]+` (note that this is case sensitive)

To use regular expressions in python, `import re`. The `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)` method will look through the entire string for the pattern you give.

More information on regular expressions in python can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html). A simple regular expression tester can be found [here](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 1):

- use `any` to check in SET for each character of string

```py
SET = set("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._")
s = "123#"
print(any(x not in SET for x in s))
```

Comment: why not just `set(s) - SET`?

Comment: You just need to know whether your string contains char that is not in S. Using any can help early stopping.

Comment: @thebjorn Depends on the string. Your way always builds the whole set while `any` stops at the first non-member. So yours is slower for example for `s = "#123456789"`. Maybe `SET.issuperset(s)` is best.

Comment: @HeapOverflow it really doesn't depend on the string though, the only degenerate cases are when the illegal char is in the first three positions of a long string. If any of those conditions are not met, e.g. if the string is short: `set("#12") - SET` is about 25% faster than the `any` version. The set implementation also has a predictable run-time since it is implemented in C while the any-loop is in Python - not to mention that the set-version is much easier to understand.

Comment: @thebjorn Not true. For `s = '123#' * 1000` the illegal char is not in the first three positions and the `any` solution is about 65 times faster than yours. Interestingly, the `issuperset` solution is about as slow as yours there, so apparently it doesn't work lazily. That's a surprising bummer.

Comment: @HeapOverflow annoyingly you're correct ;-)  See my answer for comparisons (regex seems to be best..) -- bah, it was closed before I could post my answer, but the fastest was `re.compile(r"[^-._\w\d]")`

Comment: @thebjorn That indeed seems to be fastest. Could also use `r"[^-.\w]"`, as `\w` includes digits and underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the runtime of the different solutions:

```
import timeit

search_strings = [
    '"#12"',                     # short string, early match
    '"#1234567"',                # longer string, early match
    '"1234567#"',                # longer string, late match
    '"123" * 100 + "#"',         # long string, late match
    '"123#" * 100',              # long string early match
]

algorithms = [
    ("r.search(s)", 's={};import re; r = re.compile(r"[^-.\w]")'),
    ("set(s) - SET", 's={};SET=frozenset("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._")'),
    ("any(x not in SET for x in s)", 's={};SET=frozenset("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._")'),
    ("SET.issuperset(s)", 's={};SET=frozenset("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._")'),
]

for alg, setup in algorithms:
    print alg
    for sstr in search_strings:
        print "%35s %.3f" % (sstr[:35], timeit.timeit(alg, setup.format(sstr)))
```

which gives the following output on my machine:

```
r.search(s)
                              "#12" 0.470
                         "#1234567" 0.514
                         "1234567#" 0.572
                  "123" * 100 + "#" 3.493
                       "123#" * 100 0.502
set(s) - SET
                              "#12" 0.566
                         "#1234567" 1.045
                         "1234567#" 1.075
                  "123" * 100 + "#" 7.658
                       "123#" * 100 10.170
any(x not in SET for x in s)
                              "#12" 0.786
                         "#1234567" 0.797
                         "1234567#" 1.475
                  "123" * 100 + "#" 27.266
                       "123#" * 100 1.087
SET.issuperset(s)
                              "#12" 0.466
                         "#1234567" 0.864
                         "1234567#" 0.896
                  "123" * 100 + "#" 7.512
                       "123#" * 100 10.199
```

we see that the regex solution is the fastest.